# Checking an external file with an entry within tkinter [login page]

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Im presently working on a school assignment which requires the user to have to login, using credentials from an external file- logininfo.txt - and then allows the user to play a dice game, but Im having difficulties setting up tkinter to handle the program. I had priorly made a section of code [that worked fine] to check the login details but now when handling the GUI its no longer working; Essentially, i need to know with the last section of code (including and following `with open('logininfo.txt') as file:`  ) to work within (or out of) the main loop, so whenever you click login and `validateLogin` runs, the program also checks the external file for the search_word and returns if the user is found.
At the moment it prints the else of the statement, before the credentials are input.
(Also i removed some code that i didnt think was needed for this question)
This is the first time ive ever had to use tkinter to apologies if the answer is obvious! Thank you for your time.

```
def validateLogin(username, password):
    print("username entered :", username.get())
    print("password entered :", password.get())
    return


tkWindow = Tk()  
    tkWindow.geometry('400x150')  
    tkWindow.title('Dice game---Login Page')

#username label and text entry box
usernameLabel = Label(tkWindow, text="UserName").grid(row=0, column=0)
username = StringVar()
usernameEntry = Entry(tkWindow, textvariable=username).grid(row=0, column=1)  

#password label and password entry box
passwordLabel = Label(tkWindow,text="Password").grid(row=1, column=0)  
password = StringVar()
passwordEntry = Entry(tkWindow, textvariable=password, show='*').grid(row=1, column=1)  

validateLogin = partial(validateLogin, username, password)

#login button
loginButton = Button(tkWindow, text="Login", command=validateLogin).grid(row=4, column=0)

with open('logininfo.txt') as file:
        contents = file.read()
        lookup = username
        search_word = str(lookup)
        if search_word in contents:
            print ('user found!')
        else:
            print ('user not found. would you like to sign up?')

tkWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Move the `with open(...)` section to `validateLogin` and replace `lookup = username` with `lookup = username.get()`

Comment: @Henry Thank you but unfortunately that doesnt work either! It prints "user found" right off the bat with zero input, and then doesnt respond to any logins that are placed after.

Comment: I've just tried running it and I can't reproduce your issue, all I did was move the `with` block to `validateLogin`. [Here's the code I ran](https://imgur.com/H6QO0ky) if it helps